# Running Tensorflow/Keras Using GPU with CUDA, cuDNN, Anaconda, RTX 3060 Ti

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, gpu, data-science

I am attempting to train a neural network using my new RTX 3060 Ti for the first time and have encountered a difficult error. Below is the error message:

```
2020-12-17 12:45:09.600373: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "marge.py", line 365, in <module>
    MARGE(*sys.argv[1:])
  File "marge.py", line 357, in MARGE
    filters, filt2um)
  File "lib\NN.py", line 712, in driver
    nn.train(train_batches, valid_batches, epochs, patience)
  File "lib\NN.py", line 335, in train
    model_checkpoint])
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\marge\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\marge\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 154, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\marge\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\marge\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\anaconda3\envs\marge\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(256, 7), b.shape=(7, 4096), m=256, n=4096, k=7
         [[{{node dense_1/MatMul}}]]
         [[loss/mul/_125]]
  (1) Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(256, 7), b.shape=(7, 4096), m=256, n=4096, k=7
         [[{{node dense_1/MatMul}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I am working within a Python 3.7.2 Anaconda environment on Windows 10. Here are (what I believe to be) the relevant packages installed on this environment:

```
cudnn                     7.6.5
cudnn                     7.6.5
keras                     2.2.4
keras-applications        1.0.8
keras-base                2.2.4
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0
tensorflow                1.14.0
tensorflow-base           1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0
```

Things I have tried:

- Installing the NVidia version of Tensorflow, but the commands `pip install --user nvidia-pyindex` and `pip install --user nvidia-tensorflow[horovod]` resulted in errors.
- Adding the following to the top of my code:

  config = tf.ConfigProto()

  config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

  session = tf.Session(config=config)

This didn't work either ("failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED"), but it seems that my GPU was recognized:

```
2020-12-17 12:27:24.445007: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti major: 8 minor: 6 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.71
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0
2020-12-17 12:27:24.445413: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2020-12-17 12:27:24.445639: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-12-17 12:27:24.445772: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-12-17 12:27:24.445881: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0
2020-12-17 12:27:24.445971: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N
2020-12-17 12:27:24.446221: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6712 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:06:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
```

Is it possible that the RTX 3060 Ti is not supported for this usage yet?

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide. Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:
I have also tried the suggestions of [these](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/installing-cudnn-for-gpu-support-with-tensorflow-on-windows-10-aff10c6c9929) [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) (in retrospect, installing CUDA and cuDNN seems inmportant). I also ran the commands:

```
tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
```

both of which returned "True". However, I still received the "failed to run cuBLAS routine" error. I also noticed that the 3060 Ti does not appear on NVIDEA's [list](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) of CUDA-compatible GPU's, so maybe I am just out of luck...

Answer (score 2):

I also had some struggles like you did when I was trying to run on my GPU. I don't remember well, so I am afraid that I might not be much of a help.

I see that you are using below the second version of the TensorFlow.  You have to install the right Cuda and cuDNN version for the TensorFlow 1.14 you are using.

[image]

Here is all the link you should try to install:

- Driver for your GPU: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/167753/en-us
- The right CUDA version: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive
- The right cuDNN version (you need to create an account but download the 7.4 version): https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

I hope this works and let me know if it does, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm starting to think my issue may be with the versions of the software that I have installed. I read elsewhere (https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/hg45ux/is_cuda_11_compatible_with_tensorflow/) that I need to have TF 2.4 installed, so I've done that. From that reddit thread, it looks like TF 2.4/3000 series cards require CUDA 11.0, whereas I installed CUDA 11.1.  I'm going to try downgrading my CUDA installation next.